# How to automount volumes earlier in the boot process?

Tags: macos, catalina, startup, mount, big-sur

I have a set of programs that run from directories directly off the root path (`/`) instead of the usual `/Applications`.  They have worked fine in every version of macOS including Catalina and now Big Sur.  Unfortunately, starting with Catalina, the OS does not allow you to create directories off the root anymore.

To get around this, I created a `/etc/synthetic.conf` file which allows you to define empty directories at the root that can be used as mountpoints.  I put each program its own APFS volume and use `fstab` to automount them at boot time.  It works perfectly -- sort of.

The problem is that every time I reboot my Mac, some system preferences are lost (file type/MIME associations, notification center preferences, privacy settings, LaunchPad icons, etc.) and I have to reset them every time.  The first time I launch application Foo after a reboot for example, it asks me if I want to allow notifications.  One application I use starts a VM at boot time, before a user has logged into the machine.  I have to place that VM in my '/User/' directory in order for it to work.  None of this is a huge deal, but it's very annoying.

From what I understand, macOS runs some launch daemons during the boot process looking for app bundles and populates various databases used by these features use to determine what apps are actually installed on the system.  My guess is that the `fstab` file doesn't get processed until later in the boot process, so the APFS mounts not available when those launch daemons run.

Generally speaking, how does macOS control the order of launch daemons?  And specifically, how can I get `fstab` to process earlier on?

Comment: Given that most probably Apple will continue to add protection layers to macOS wouldn't it be easier to move these applications to /Applications etc?

Comment: Are you using filevault? I don't know the answer to the ordering question, but you may be able to mount the volumes a little earlier directly from a system launchdaemon; if they have a dependent order, I'd say mount them all from a single daemon.

Comment: @abathur; Yes to FileVault. Can you elaborate on the system launchdaemon? Do you know which one does it?

Comment: Are you also separately encrypting these individual volumes (do they need to be explicitly decrypted to mount)? I'm not certain we're on the same page. I'm talking about adding your own launchdaemon. (Though, AFAIK, the answer to your question is that diskarbitrationd is responsible for a normal mount).